# Kivy Screen Manager: Binding Dynamically Added Buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I have the code below to the display .txt files in a usb and need to access all of them separately. All files display in scrollview but I can't understand how to actually utilize or press these buttons to go to another screen. Each one needs to be bound to a new screen.

```
            self.file_name = os.listdir(TXT)
            layout = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
            base = ["element {}".format(i) for i in range(len(os.listdir(TXT)))]
            layout = GridLayout(cols = 1, spacing = 10, size_hint_y = None)
            layout.bind(minimum_height = layout.setter("height"))

            L = [x for x in range(len(os.listdir(TXT)))]
            for x in L:
                layout.add_widget(Button(text=self.file_names[x]))
            scrollview = ScrollView(size_hint=(.5, None), size = (Window.width, Window.height), pos_hint={'x':.265, 'center_y': .5})
            scrollview.add_widget(layout)
            self.add_widget(scrollview)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on_press` while defining your button and then use lambda to define the function that you can to run when the button is pressed.

```
for i in L:
    layout.add_widget(Button(text=self.file_names[x], on_press: lambda x: some_function()))
```

Also if you function takes i (or x in your code) as paramter then you have to do so like this:

```
for i in L:
    layout.add_widget(Button(text=self.file_names[x], on_press: lambda x,y=i: some_function(i)))
```

otherwise it will just take the last value of `i`